# Download and Download Manager Examples in Qt documentation

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

for this example，from the Qt documentation , http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-download.html the program first read all data to the buffer ,then all data are written to the disk from the buffer ,right ?

then for this example，from the Qt documentation , http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-downloadmanager.html the program is reading and writing data all the time ,right ?

and which way is more proper ？

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that 'more proper way' applicable in this case, they both have pro and cons and obviously depends on what you trying to build.

Depends what functionality you need. If you need only 'completed' items to be saved and their are size relatively small to be kept in memory you can first fetch and them save. If you dont know upfront which items size you are working with and want to have things like 'continue interrupted download' then you should probably save things as they are coming from the network.